# Flink: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: AvroSchemaConverter

Tags: java, apache-flink, pom.xml

I am trying to connect to Kafka. When I run a simple JAR file, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.formats.avro.typeutils.AvroSchemaConverter.convertToSchema(Lorg/apache/flink/table/types/logical/LogicalType;)Lorg/apache/avro/Schema
```

Yes, I am aware that `NoSuchMethod` can potentially mean that there is a conflict between versions; however, there is no Flink instance running on YARN cluster.

I have also tried to play with `pom.xml` but no luck

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <flink.version>1.13.2</flink.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <scala.binary.version>2.12</scala.binary.version>
    <confluent.version>5.2.1</confluent.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-sql-connector-kafka_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-table-planner-blink_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-avro-confluent-registry</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-sql-avro</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-statebackend-rocksdb_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-jdbc_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Flink Dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-hive_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-table-api-java-bridge_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-table-planner_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.azercell.bigdata.flink_data_calculator.flinkBalance</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>org.codehaus.plexus.util</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>org.shaded.plexus.util</shadedPattern>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The versions are indicated above. I was able to connect to Hive; it's when I am trying to connect to Kafka, the problem arises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with dependency. The trick was to either remove Avro `1.11.0` from Flink, or remove Avro `1.7.7` from Hive. I ended up removing Avro `1.11.0` and replacing it with a different Avro version:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-sql-avro-confluent-registry</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-avro</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2-cdh6.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Another way that will also work is to use `hive-exec::core` and `hive-metastore` as dependencies.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly Flink 1.13.2 has switched to Apache Avro `1.10.0`, so that's quite probably the issue You are facing since You are trying to use the `1.8.2` avro lib.

Comment: That's correct. I will be posting a solution in a bit. However, you are correct in the root-cause of the problem.